# Disable Copy/Paste into a specific folder - C#

Tags: c#

I have this C# program:

TestProgram:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);            
    var directory = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(path, "folder"));
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(directory.FullName, "example.txt")))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("hi");
    }
    var directorySecurity = directory.GetAccessControl();
    var administratorRule = new FileSystemAccessRule("Administrators", FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow);
    var usersRole = new FileSystemAccessRule("Users", FileSystemRights.Read, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow);
    directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(administratorRule);
    directorySecurity.AddAccessRule(usersRole);
    directory.SetAccessControl(directorySecurity);            
}
```

So, I want to create a directory which only *Administrators* can edit the name and the content.

In order to test this code snippet, I've copied this directory into **C:** and I've created a `usertest` which is member of **Users** group and stop.
This works fine because `usertest` cannot edit `example.txt`.

But, if I (as `usertest`) create a `test.txt` file on `C:\Users\usertest\Desktop` and copy/paste into `C:\folder` created by the execution of `TestProgram.exe`, the operation is successful.

How can I edit the C# program in order to avoid the copy/paste into folder?

### EDIT:

On **C:** folder, the `Users` group (`usertest` is a member of it) has these rights:

- Read and execute
- Read
- List folder content

So, how can I inhibit the inheritance from **C:** to folder?

Comment: I suspect your NTFS permissions are wrong. Have you tried looking at them in the Windows Explorer properties dialog?

Comment: @RichardDeeming is right. Your folder is probably inheriting from parent folder and `usertest` has more rights than specified. You can make your ACL protected (breaking inheritance) to ensure only your granted ACEs are set.

Comment: @Hazrelle I would advice against using some rare acronims like Access Control Entry

Comment: Ok @Cleptus. [ACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/20233ed8-a6c6-4097-aafa-dd545ed24428) = Access Control List, [ACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/d06e5a81-176e-46c6-9cf7-9137aad4455e) = Access Control Entry.

Comment: @RichardDeeming You're right. On C:\  folder, Users group, usertest so, have "Read & execute", "List folder content" and "read" rights. uhmm

Comment: Because the usertest is the owner of the file is always has access to it,  maybe you need to take ownership of the file for another user... it that's the problem tell me.. I can than give you the answer how to take ownership.

Comment: @RuiCaramalho nope, the owner of example.txt is Administrator. usertest is the owner of the second file (test.txt).

Comment: You can use `SetAccessRuleProtection` in the `DirectorySecurity` object to establish the inheritance (allow or remove it) and protection (whether the inheritance can modify your specific rules or not) ( [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection?view=net-6.0#System_Security_AccessControl_ObjectSecurity_SetAccessRuleProtection_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using c#, you can call [DirectorySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection?view=net-6.0#System_Security_AccessControl_ObjectSecurity_SetAccessRuleProtection_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_) and make the `bool preserveInheritance` to false.

To stop inheritance in Windows 11:

> Windows explorer -> Right click on the folder -> Select the menu option named "Properties" -> Change to the tab named "Security" -> Click the button named "Advanced Settings" -> Hit the button at the bottom named "Disable inheritance".

The Advanced Settings option has a really useful tab named "Effective access" where you can see what can actually do users or groups to that object.

Comment: Or it could be solved via code (as the question is doing), by using `DirectorySecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection()`. Answering a question that sets permissions through code by making a user use Windows Explorer doesn't really make a lot of sense (even if the answer is right :-) )